# Spring integration groovy scripting

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How can i use registered beans in

For example like this:

```
<chain>
<si-groovy:script>
def check = myCheckBean.checkPayload(payload)
myLogBean.log(paylod)
if (check==null) throws new Exception("Verify falt")
</si-groovy:script>
<chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your config looks bad. Should be something like this:

```
<chain>
   <service-activator>
       <si-groovy:script>
              def check = myCheckBean.checkPayload(payload)
              myLogBean.log(paylod)
              if (check==null) throws new Exception("Verify falt")
       </si-groovy:script>
   <service-activator>
<chain>
```

Starting with [Spring Integration 3.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#groovy) Groovy Scripts have access to `BeanFactory`, so you can use any bean from the Context by its bean name. So, your code is compatible with Spring Integration 3.0.

If you use previous version of Spring Integration we strongly recommend to upgrade, as long as they are EOL already.

Comment: Usefully tip. For future processing need to add return payload

Comment: If it's OK, why don't follow with rule 'Accept Asnwer'?